# required int but there is a problem and found zero bytes

Tags: java, file, file-io, int, long-integer

How to solve this?

```
    File f=new File("d:/tester.txt");
    long size=f.length();  // returns the size in bytes
    char buff[]=new char[size]; // line of ERROR
                // will not accept long in it's argument
                // I can't do the casting (loss of data)
```

Is it possible to use `size` as the length of `buff` without the loss of data?

### If yes how can i use it?

**My second question is :**

Why i am not getting the actual number of bytes?

This is the program :

```
import java.io.*;
class tester {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
 File f=new File("c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts.File");
 long x=f.length();  // returns the number of bytes read from the file
 System.out.println("long-> " + x );
}
```

}

The output is `long-> 0` ,but obviously it is not so.Why do i get this result?

Comment: sorry to post 2 questions.But was unable to submit only 1 question.Stack overflow said unable to meet our quality standards!Don't know the reason for that.May be the length was too short for 1 question..

Comment: are you sure the file exists? `File.length()` returns `0L` if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: @ sverre yeah! I am using win7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast the long to an int

```
char buff[]=new char[(int) size];
```

This will only work for files less than 2 GB in size.

However, if you intend to use this to read the file perhaps you meant

```
byte[] buff=new byte[(int) size];
```

I would look at [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) and [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) from Apache Commons IO which has lots of help methods.

---

I doubt you have a file with that name. perhaps you need to drop the `.File` at the end which sounds like an odd extension.

I would check `f.exists()` first.

Comment: For files larger than 2 GB (actually 100 MB is large enough to avoid), I wouldn't read them all at once. You should read them a block (for binary) or line (for text) at a time. Your hosts files should be much smaller than this.

Comment: @ Peter Lawrey but i have a file named `hosts` with extension `.File`

Comment: @Suhail Gupta I think you're confusing the *Type* of file with the file extension. Try it without the extension.

Comment: @ Zach L `can you tell me the difference.` yes i have tried without the extension and it works.

Comment: I have never heard of an extension called `.File` and I have been using MS-DOS/Windows since version 2.0.  What would be the point of calling a file a `.File` Isn't it a file already?

Comment: @Suhail Gupta  Windows Explorer displays a column with the header Type, that I suspect you were looking at. That is Windows' description of the file (for example, SomeDocument.doc might have the Type "Word Document"). An extension is the last part of a file name, after and including the last dot in the name (for example, SomeDocument.doc has the extension .doc). Files (like the `hosts` file you were getting the length of) do not always need extensions.